# WSO2ESB: Your connection is not secure

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

When I am hitting localhost:9443/carbon, browser giving error, Your connection is not secure

Comment: Are you using https?

Comment: @ElTête yes, I am using https

Comment: Can you give us more information about the warning? Maybe the algorithms is obsolete, etc, etc. [check](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/6098869?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

This is because default primary keystore (used for SSL) is self signed by WSO2. In production env, you should change it

See https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Configuring+Keystores

Comment: I make changes whatever mention on link but still I am getting same error

Comment: Are you using self signed certificates?

Comment: if you are using a self signed (by yourself) certificate, this is the same problem, your are not in the list of trusted CA in your browser. You can update this list, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7580508/getting-chrome-to-accept-self-signed-localhost-certificate